# debug gke loadbalancing error - some backend services are in UNHEALTHY state

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing

Started seeing this error for the first time in a year and unsure how to debug (not very familiar with k8s)

{@type: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry, statusDetails: failed_to_pick_backend}

Answer (score 3):

**failed_to_pick_backend** - The load balancer failed to pick a healthy backend to handle the request.

Debug tips:

- List the pods the load balancer pointing to.
- Make sure that [probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) (ie. readiness, liveness) are configured.
- Describe the pods ( `kubectl describe pods <pod_name> -n <namespace>`) to see why the health check is failing.
- Fix the health check problem. Once the pods are healthy, give the load balancer some time (sometimes it takes hours) to update the status.